# Linear algebra through applications for engineering kids

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, education

I am going to teach Linear algebra-I to first-year engineering students of all disciplines.
The syllabus is typical: starting from what is a vector, linear span, linearly independent, $\dots$ , spectral theorem for real symmetric matrices.

I am planning to keep my course like this: along with each concept, I would like to add a simple engineering/real-life application.  Over the course, I want these applications to be spread over different engineering branches so that no one feels left out. I believe that this way students will appreciate the subject better.

Given this, what are some books/articles in which I can find the applications of basic linear algebra concepts? I am ready to learn some engineering topics to deliver the applications correctly to the students. So kindly share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but there's some cool math involving vector forces keeping satellites in orbit: https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-4/Circular-Motion-Principles-for-Satellites

Comment: @G When you say "engineering kids", how old are these students? Middle school? High school? University?

Comment: @G If you want applications of linear systems of equations, some obvious equations are circuits in electrical engineering (which get difficult if you have multiple voltage sources!) and statics. One nice application of the spectral theorem is to the principal stresses of the [Cauchy stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor). I think it would be worth throwing in applications of linear algebra to computer graphics for good measure.

Comment: @BenGrossmann University students